# Typescript: no error for argument of type never passed to a type predicate function, but also no warning about unreachable code

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
type NumberOrString = number | string;

// This type predicate is intentionally malformed, it should return "arg is number"
// but suppose that developer made a mistake
function isNumber(arg: NumberOrString): arg is NumberOrString {
    return true;
}

function isString(arg: NumberOrString): arg is string {
    return typeof arg === 'string';
}

function doSomething(arg: NumberOrString) {
    if (isNumber(arg)) {
        console.log('Argument is number');
    } else if (isString(arg)) { // <marked line>
        console.log('Argument is string');
    } else {
        console.log('We should not be here, but anyway...');
    }
}
```

The `isNumber` check is intentionally malformed, and returns a bad type predicate, which domain is strictly equal to argument type.
Now, in  TS seems to infer type of `arg` as `never`. But function `isString` expects `number | string`, so I would expect that in that line:

- either TS puts a warning about bad argument type (argument `arg` of type `never` is not assignable to `number | string`)
- or TS figures out that code after the first `if`-block is unreachable.

Meanwhile, neither of these happens. Could someone explain to me what am I missing, or point me to a bug in TS which describes the problem?
I would also be grateful for pointing out if there is a workaround for this -- a way of writing code which helps TS to check similar constructions in better way. Maybe using [assertions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) is a way?

I did a brief search in Typescript repo to find similar bugs, and these seem to be similar although a bit different: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50363, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49640

Comment: RE: unreachable code: TS's control flow analysis isn't that powerful. If you do `if (true) { whatever } else {somethingElse }` you'll get a warning about unreachable code, but if you have `if (callToFunctionThatJustReturnsTrue()) ...` you won't. As for why it correctly gives never as the type in the else-if but doesn't error, I have no idea, great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`never` is assignable to all types. An example that helped me understand this was of sets:

Think of a type as `Set {N,U,M,B,E,R}` (type number). Now type string is say, `Set {S,T,R,I,N,G}`. Now these types don't intersect. Also, neither is a subset of the other, so we can say one is not assignable to another. If we have to think of a set representation for never it is an empty `Set`. And an empty Set is a subset of any other set and hence assignable to any other type.

`never` is usually for values that will `never` be. From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> The never type represents the type of values that never occur. For instance, never is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns. Variables also acquire the type never when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

This is the key statement:

**The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself).**

So, that is why TS never complains for your second condition. `never` is simply assignable to anything. It is the logical opposite of `unknown` in that manner.

Regarding the unreachable bit, the warning shows up for code unreachable during run time. As you can see Typescript cannot say that the a developer will only pass a string/number to your function. They can pass a boolean and in that case the code will be reached during run-time. So TS never complains. Here is the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#unreachable-code):

> Statements guaranteed to not be executed at run time are now correctly flagged as unreachable code errors. For instance, statements following unconditional return, throw, break or continue statements are considered unreachable.

Comment: Follow this Github issue for other explanations: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28982

Comment: Excellent answer, I appreciate details and links! Thanks a lot!
Just for the sake of discussion, do you see any way or approach (or TS mechanism that I don't know about) which would allow TS to display at least some kind of error here? I'm talking about "other ways to write code which does similar thing".
Example in question is simple on purpose, but we actually had a similar problem in a real-world project, and it was caught too late.